# TYPO3 Fluid FAL images get wrong path if I will show it as background image

Tags: typo3, background-image, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, fal

Hi I'm working with [FluidTYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/Inline/FalViewHelper.html) and the latest `TYPO3 Core 7.6` and Flux/Fluid Extensions.

I'm using a FAL-relation with:

```
<flux:field.inline.fal name="backgroundimage" minItems="1" maxItems="1" />
```

Now I can show my Image in frontend with the following snippet (the for/each is obsolet, I only have one image):

```
<f:for each="{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'backgroundimage')}" as="image">
    <f:image treatIdAsReference="1" src="{image.id}" alt=""/><br/>
</f:for>
```

The image will be rendering like `<img src="fileadmin/user_upload/.."`

But I need my Image as a Background Image, so I've tried:

```
<f:for each="{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'backgroundimage')}" as="image">
 <div class="back" style="background-image: url('{image.id}');"></div>
</f:for>
```

But I'll get .. `<div class="back" style="background-image: url('1:/Editors_English/image.jpg');"></div>`

I think the `treatIdAsReference` is missing, but how does it works? I don't know .. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do basically the same thing as you did with the image in a `<img>`-tag: Use a ViewHelper to render the image URL for you. In this case, you want only the URL, without the `<img>` tag around it, so you have to use the ViewHelper `f:uri.image` instead. It's also helpful to use it in inline notation, which will look like this:

```
<f:for each="{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'backgroundimage')}" as="image">
  <div class="back" style="background-image: url('{f:uri.image(src: image.id, treatIdAsReference: 1)}');"></div>
</f:for>
```

I'm not sure if you actually need the `treatIdAsReference` parameter, you can probably leave it out.

Comment: Thanks Jost. It works perfect. The parameter `treatIdAsReference` isn't necessary, you're right.